# How to get reactive validation with array group?

Tags: forms, validation, angular6

I have set code this way

```
errorGroup: any = FormGroup;

this.errorGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    errors: this.formBuilder.array([])
});
```

For repeat/add new data in group I have add this function which works fine.

```
addErrorGroup() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
        error_code: ['',[Validators.required ]]            
    })
}
```

Get controls by this way. I think hear I'm missing something.

```
get f() { return this.errorGroup.controls.errors; }
```

In HTML

```
<select formControlName="error_code" name="error_code" (change)="errorCodeChange($event.target.value , i)">
    <option *ngFor="..." value={{...}}>{{...}}</option>
</select>
<span *ngIf="f.error_code.errors.required" class="error-msg">This is required field.</span>
```

I got this error.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined
```

Comment: Is that error coming from your TS (`this.errorGroup.controls.errors`) or from your HTML (`*ngIf="f.error_code.errors.required'`) ?

Comment: @prettyfly When I'm trying to read erros from HTML

Answer (score 0):

If that error is coming from HTML, it's because your `*ngIf` condition is trying to read a value from an undefined object.

At the point where the view is rendered, and checked, it's entirely possible that `f` (incidentally, you should change that variable name to something more descriptive, but ‍♂️) doesn't have any errors populated yet, so will be undefined.

You can do one of two things here, either, you can wrap the whole thing in another `*ngIf` to ensure the `error_code` part of `f` is populate before accessing it:

```
<span *ngIf="f && f.error_code">
    <span *ngIf="f.error_code.errors.required" class="error-msg">This is required field.</span>
</span>
```

Or, you can use the safe navigation operator:

```
<span *ngIf="f?.error_code?.errors?.required" class="error-msg">This is required field.</span>
```

Note the `?` after each object key. This bails out when it hits the first null value, but, the app continues to work as it fails gracefully.

You can read more about it here: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Comment: But when it fire ? I need to display this messages when I clicked on button.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you just do below?

```
<span *ngIf="errorGroup.get('error_code').errors.required" class="error-msg">
  This is required field.
</span>
```

so by doing this way, you don't need the f() getter in your component file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried but I got error.  Cannot read property 'errors' of null